# Mosaicking rasters in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, imagery, satellite, mosaic

I am a new user of GRASS GIS.

How can I mosaic different satellite imageries using GRASS GUI?

I was trying to use i.image.mosaic, but could not succeed. I have been looking for an online tutorial but could not find one.

Answer (score 8):

You can use r.patch for that (see [help file](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.patch.html))

You probably want to set the region first to encompass all raster layers, after which you can use r.patch to 'mosaic' the layers. The following example is from the helpfile:

```
export MAPS=`g.mlist type=rast sep=, pat="map_*"` 
g.region rast=$MAPS -p
r.patch in=$MAPS out=mosaic
```

Use the keyword `export` when you are using a Linux and Bash combination.